# Importing dxf as a vector layer or using dxf2shp function (Differences?)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I was trying to import a DXF file in QGIS. First tried using dxf2shp function but it didn´t work. I browse the dxf file and i put a name to the output and nothing was created in directory i chose.  I couldn´t convert a DFX file in order to import it with this method, i dont know what i did wrong.

I tried in other way with "add vector layer" selecting (Source: file,code:UTF-8; and Browse my dxf) and it works.

what is the difference between the 2 ways, is there a disadvantage with the vector layer option?

Do you know why first method didn´t work for me?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dxf2shp is dead so you should use the Add Vector Layer method from here on in.

Comment: what you mean, that option doesn't work but it is there?

Comment: Yes no longer maintained. Has been removed from 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Nathan so i think Add Vector Laver always was the best option.